# useDefaultCredentials doesn't seem to be forming a request to proxy with any credentials

Tags: .net, wcf, webclient

I have a set up with a proxy in between my client and application server. Basically, I don't know if there is something I'm missing (I had this working earlier, and it's broken now with no apparent reason for it.) but when I try to make a http request through my web client and a proxy is set in my IE settings, the request is made without default credentials even though my config file DOES INFACT contain:

```
     <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/> 
  </system.net>
```

Can't figure out how or why this silly thing won't work, considering I am clearly providing the credentials needed. I have tried all sorts of different properties set ups in default proxy and non seem to make the slighest bit of difference.

Any one know of some thing I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone who runs into this problem and is connecting to a proxy, make sure that the authentication type for the client and the proxy are the same. If one is different from the other, the credentials will not be sent. For example, if you have a proxy that uses basic authentication and a client using ntlm or kerberos, you will have problems.